# 導入したphpMyAdminページへのアクセス時にForbiddenエラーが表示されてしまう

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin

Mac OS High Sierra (Apache2.4, PHP7.1, MySQL8.0)でPhpMyAdminの導入できた方いらっしゃいますか？
現在インターネット上のあるあらゆる方法を試したみましたがForbiddenを解消するに至りません。成功されている方がいらっしゃいましたら導入されている環境を教えてください。

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
```

参考にした内容
[【macOS Sierra】Mac OSX 10.12 macOS Sierra にAMP環境の構築【初心者必見】【続編】](https://qiita.com/keneo/items/8bee152aee75123b7a07)
[Install Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin on macOS Sierra](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/)

実際に`WebServer/Documents/`以下に入れる方法で互換性があるのか確認したく投稿しました。

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | %         |
| laravel          | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Comment: 環境を教えてほしいというよりも、環境が構築したい（forbidddenを解消したい）ということですよね？また実施した内容を記述していただくと求めている回答が得られると思います。

Comment: 実際に行った内容を記載できますか？URLの記事のとおり実施してどこでForbiddenとなってしまうのでしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず macOS High Sierra (10.13.5), PHP 7.1.16 で Qiita の記事の手順を試しましたが、phpMyAdmin のログインページの確認までは行けました。

Answer (score -1):

Apache2 の httpd.conf で PHP5 or PHP7 が有効になっているか確認してください。
`LoadModule php7_module` の先頭に `#` が付いているとコメントアウトされているため、有効になっていません。

例えば Vim で httpd.conf を編集する場合、`#` を外して `:wq` で保存してみてください。